# Cordova failed to launch app on Android emulator

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans, android-emulator

I installed Cordova 4.2.0 and tried to launch my cordovaApp on android emulator.
I got this error message:

```
Failed to launch app on emulator: Failed to install apk to emulator: Error executing "adb -s
emulator-5556 install -r "C:\xampp\htdocs\CordovaApp\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-
debug.apk"": failed to copy 'C:\xampp\htdocs\CordovaApp\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp- 
debug.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/CordovaApp-debug.apk': No such file or directory

Command finished with error code 8: C:\xampp\htdocs\CordovaApp\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat
--emulator
Error: C:\xampp\htdocs\CordovaApp\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit
code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone 
(C:\Users\windows8new\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-  
lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
C:\xampp\htdocs\CordovaApp\nbproject\build.xml:275: exec returned: 1
```

I'm new in this so I don't know what to do. Can somebody help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you get any solution?? I am facing the same issue...